# Weird current in Push-Pull converter for high voltage multiplier

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a push-pull converter driving a Villard-type voltage multiplier. The converter is built as naive as it could be: Two stacked MOSFETs with free wheeling diodes for the push-pull half opposing two stacked capacitors for the voltage divider that creates the center.
In between there is the step up transformer that drives the Villard rectifier.

Now what I am experiencing is that at low to medium loads the current in the transformer's primary winding looks like one would expect: Triangular increasing (in magnitude) slopes during the corresponding on-times of the MOSFETs and decreasing (towards zero) slopes during the free wheeling. That is, it is operating in discontinuous mode.

When load is increased, however, at a certain load level the winding current does not increase further but starts to decrease during the on-times of the MOSFETs. Depending on the on-time the current (in either direction/in either half of the switching cycle) can be monitored to decrease down to zero.

I have checked the following:

- Input voltage stays constant.
- Center voltage (capacitive divider) stays constant, i.e. the current is not collapsing due to the voltage rail coming down.
- The active MOSFETs actually stays switched on as it should.
- The other one stays off.
- There is no excessive heat dissipated in the MOSFETs, so the switching should be somewhat correct.
- The winding current is actually there. I assumed a measuring artifact, so I verified with a current probe.

I am aware that at this state my question is rather vague. Yet I hope it may ring a bell for someone and I will add further details and especially oscilloscope snapshots soon.

Thank you & Best regards

Comment: What you are experiencing may be called load regulation error where the series impedance matches the load, so when you have reached maximum power transfer, the source and load impedance must be the same.  Can you define all the impedances in your components?  Primary inductance, frequency, mutual inductance , primary and secondary DCR, turns ratio, load R, and thus Voc/Isc=Z  The diode cap loads will appear a  pulse width modulated ESR+Rs(diode)=R divided by duty cycle since C will be much lower impedance at the applied f.  It may not be the best for low ripple, high efficiency HVDC output.

Comment: Just to anticipate the latter, I assume that despite of this Push-Pull/Villard architecture there is not a lot of options left for HVDC generation at 100kV and more :-/

Comment: @Kamajii You might skim [DIY Physics HV Supplies](http://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/) and [250 kV HV DC Supply](http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/).

Comment: I agree that method has been used for decades. I borrowed equipment once with diode cap multipliers that stood 0.5m high to go from 50kV to 200kV, but I was only measuring insulation leakage and PD.  Fascinating E-fields with PD discharges on the wall far away in the factory, static discharges from painted steel fences, transformer paint etc.  What are you testing?

Comment: Turn on an AM or SW radio and check that you are not getting PD loading effects. It will sound like lightning strokes on the radio, but could be silent in your system

Comment: @jonk: Marx is not DC, and the other DCs are exactly what I am doing here :)

Comment: Which picture best describes your setup?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: As ancient as they may be, Villard multipliers are still state of the art, even in professional laboratory equipment. It probably is the only design whose creepage and clearances naturally improve with increasing high voltage...

Comment: The impedance must be transformed into the source by ratio Vo/Vi². What are your source and load impedance? I think it is easy to use a BIL200 AC transformer with BIL400 (x2)cascaded bushings than rectify than  use low voltage DC to multiply with that. Still waiting for your answers.  ( for example) I used two 0.5m BIL 200kV bushings in series to prevent DC arcs with Nylon 4x8' panels to insulate to tank  I What is the purpose of the equipment? leakage current?

Comment: PDIV testing???

Comment: If the current reaches a plateau you may be saturating the core. Can you tell me a little about the core? Material, cross sectional area, gap distance, number of windings etc. (unless it is a COTS product then just post the data sheet)